# Query notification equivalent for SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, event-notification

I was looking for query notification to get notified on multiple client for a specific table changes. It seems that [this feature has been removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms181122(v=sql.105)) in SQL Server 2008 R2. Documentation is not very clear about that.

When exactly has this been removed (which version exactly)?

Is there any other way to manage that without additional components?

Comment: Can you define "additional components"? I can think of other options to accomplish the same task, but they are other features in SQL Server.

Comment: I was thinking of things like [trigger based solutions like that](https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Query Notifications have not been removed or changed.  The Documentation has just not all been ported to learn.microsoft.com.

See, eg:

[Working with Query Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/working-with-query-notifications?view=sql-server-2017)

[Query Notifications - sys.dm_qn_subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/query-notifications-sys-dm-qn-subscriptions?view=sql-server-2017)

[Detecting Changes with SqlDependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency)

Comment: Thanks, but I was basing my assumption on [that page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms175110(v%3dsql.105)) where it says in the header "This content has been retired..."

Comment: "This content has been retired..." just means that it's part of old documentation.  It happens to still be accurate.